# Elasticsearch: Penalize documents that have similar neighbors to de-cluster

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch instance filled with job listings, and when a user searches, it aims to return relevant results.  However, we have many copies of each job but at different locations, and since those are all very relevant to the search, they turn up at the top of the list, cluttering results.

Here is an example:

```
Search: facebook

Results:
 - Facebook Engineering Internship
   Atlanta, Georgia
 - Facebook Engineering Internship
   Madison, Wisconsin
 - Facebook Engineering Internship
   Palo Alto, California
```

What I would like to do here is de-cluster results that are too similar, effectively penalizing a particular document result based on the document that is returned right before it.  That would enable the top results to have more variety, looking something more like this:

```
Search: facebook

Results:
 - Facebook Engineering Internship
   Atlanta, Georgia
 - Facebook Marketing Trainee
   Palo Alto, California
 - Social Media Expert: Facebook (Verizon)
   Chicago, Illinois
 - Facebook Engineering Internship
   Madison, Wisconsin
```

How can I do this? If I'm conceptualizing this the wrong way with penalizing documents based on neighbors, please let me know that as well.

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html